# Why packages issued as security relevant updates first, but changed later to normal updates?

Tags: 12.04, updates

I'm running an Ubuntu 12.04 server.
I used to observe multiple times that they were some packages issued as security updates first, but changed later to normal updates.

Here's a concrete example:
Some days ago, my monitoring reported me security updates.
Immediately, I connected to the server over ssh and ran the following command:

```
root@perseus:~# apt-get -s dist-upgrade |grep "^Inst" |grep -i securi
Inst dpkg [1.16.1.2ubuntu7.5] (1.16.1.2ubuntu7.6 Ubuntu:12.04/precise-security [amd64])
Inst dpkg-dev [1.16.1.2ubuntu7.5] (1.16.1.2ubuntu7.6 Ubuntu:12.04/precisesecurity [all]) []
Inst libdpkg-perl [1.16.1.2ubuntu7.5] (1.16.1.2ubuntu7.6 Ubuntu:12.04/precise-security [all])
root@perseus:~# apt-get -s dist-upgrade |grep "^Inst" |grep -i securi
Inst dpkg [1.16.1.2ubuntu7.5] (1.16.1.2ubuntu7.6 Ubuntu:12.04/precise-security [amd64])
Inst dpkg-dev [1.16.1.2ubuntu7.5] (1.16.1.2ubuntu7.6 Ubuntu:12.04/precisesecurity [all]) []
Inst libdpkg-perl [1.16.1.2ubuntu7.5] (1.16.1.2ubuntu7.6 Ubuntu:12.04/precise-security [all]).2ubuntu7.6 Ubuntu:12.04/precise-security [amd64])
Inst dpkg-dev [1.16.1.2ubuntu7.5] (1.16.1.2ubuntu7.6 Ubuntu:12.04/precisesecurity [all]) []
Inst libdpkg-perl [1.16.1.2ubuntu7.5] (1.16.1.2ubuntu7.6 Ubuntu:12.04/precise-security [all])
```

Then I logged out...

Severals hours later my monitoring reported, there are no longer security updates available, but I had no updates installed (package `unattended-upgrades` is not installed as well).
I ran the following command:

```
root@perseus:~# apt-get -s dist-upgrade |grep "^Inst"
Inst dpkg [1.16.1.2ubuntu7.5] (1.16.1.2ubuntu7.6 Ubuntu:12.04/precise-updates [amd64])
Inst libc6-dev [2.15-0ubuntu10.11] (2.15-0ubuntu10.12 Ubuntu:12.04/precise-updates [amd64]) []
Inst libc-dev-bin [2.15-0ubuntu10.11] (2.15-0ubuntu10.12 Ubuntu:12.04/precise-updates [amd64]) []
Inst linux-libc-dev [3.2.0-79.115] (3.2.0-80.116 Ubuntu:12.04/precise-updates [amd64]) []
Inst libc-bin [2.15-0ubuntu10.11] (2.15-0ubuntu10.12 Ubuntu:12.04/precise-updates [amd64]) [libc6:amd64 ]
Inst libc6 [2.15-0ubuntu10.11] (2.15-0ubuntu10.12 Ubuntu:12.04/precise-updates [amd64])
Inst libtasn1-3-dev [2.10-1ubuntu1.2] (2.10-1ubuntu1.3 Ubuntu:12.04/precise-updates [amd64]) []
Inst libtasn1-3 [2.10-1ubuntu1.2] (2.10-1ubuntu1.3 Ubuntu:12.04/precise-updates [amd64])
Inst libtiff4-dev [3.9.5-2ubuntu1.7] (3.9.5-2ubuntu1.8 Ubuntu:12.04/precise-updates [amd64]) []
Inst libtiffxx0c2 [3.9.5-2ubuntu1.7] (3.9.5-2ubuntu1.8 Ubuntu:12.04/precise-updates [amd64]) []
Inst libtiff4 [3.9.5-2ubuntu1.7] (3.9.5-2ubuntu1.8 Ubuntu:12.04/precise-updates [amd64])
Inst linux-image-3.2.0-80-generic (3.2.0-80.116 Ubuntu:12.04/precise-updates [amd64])
Inst multiarch-support [2.15-0ubuntu10.11] (2.15-0ubuntu10.12 Ubuntu:12.04/precise-updates [amd64])
Inst binutils [2.22-6ubuntu1.2] (2.22-6ubuntu1.3 Ubuntu:12.04/precise-updates [amd64])
Inst dpkg-dev [1.16.1.2ubuntu7.5] (1.16.1.2ubuntu7.6 Ubuntu:12.04/precise-updates [all]) []
Inst libdpkg-perl [1.16.1.2ubuntu7.5] (1.16.1.2ubuntu7.6 Ubuntu:12.04/precise-updates [all])
Inst linux-headers-3.2.0-80 (3.2.0-80.116 Ubuntu:12.04/precise-updates [all])
Inst linux-headers-3.2.0-80-generic (3.2.0-80.116 Ubuntu:12.04/precise-updates [amd64])
Inst linux-server [3.2.0.76.90] (3.2.0.80.94 Ubuntu:12.04/precise-updates [amd64]) []
Inst linux-image-server [3.2.0.76.90] (3.2.0.80.94 Ubuntu:12.04/precise-updates [amd64]) []
Inst linux-headers-server [3.2.0.76.90] (3.2.0.80.94 Ubuntu:12.04/precise-updates [amd64])
```

Is there anybody who can explain why these package updates change from security to normal? Is there something wrong with my server?

My sources.list looks like this:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing the behavior as you are using the -security repositories and packages go through a testing process before they are released.

The security team manages a private ppa for testing - see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/UpdateProcedures for details

Next the package is released into the security repo

> -security includes only updated packages that contain security-related fixes, and are built to not require anything from "-updates". Anything built for "-security" is built on top of which ever version of a package is newest between "-updates" and "-security", so that nothing in "-security" will introduce bug regressions.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/FAQ#Repositories

So as the packages are built and tested they are going to go through a series of repositories starting with the private security ppa and moving into -security and then into the other repos.

The exact migration is going to vary with the severity of the security problem, testing, and what, if anything, may be needed in the other repositories, and eventually the packages are in -main once they are packaged by the -main maintainer.

I am going to guess that the security team maintains ppa and -security and other packages or MOTU maintain -main or -universe with varying degrees of overlap in the maintainers depending on the package.